# How to bind in reactive forms which is the formcontrolname and ngmodel in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```
<form nz-form [formGroup]="taskFormGroup" (submit)="saveFormData()">
        <div nz-row *ngFor="let remark of checklis>
          <div nz-col nzXXl="12" *ngFor="let task of remark.tasks" style="padding: .5rem;">
<nz-form-item>
                  <nz-form-control>
                    <nz-radio-group formControlName="status" name="status" (change)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                      <label nz-radio nzValue="true">Passed</label>
                      <label nz-radio nzValue="false">Failed</label>
                    </nz-radio-group>
                  </nz-form-control>
                </nz-form-item>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
checklist = [
    {
      "id": "txv3vvBr8KYB",
      "assetType": {
        "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
        "code": "PRD",
        "name": "Printing1"
      },
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "1fKBO4w0XHg7H",
          "name": "Task 1",
          "description": "Check oil spill"
        },
        {
          "id": "ESOSA6aCrOER",
          "name": "Sample1",
          "description": "Desc1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "EwQciw9whx6B",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "1nU7uASqfvLPD",
          "name": "TASK8888",
          "description": "DESC8888"
        },
        {
          "id": "EwQciw9whx6B",
          "name": "TASK9999",
          "description": "DESC9999"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

constructor (private fb: FormBuilder) {}

createTaskFormGroup() {
    const DATA = this.asset;

    return this.fb.group({
      remark: DATA || '',
      status: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

onChangeStatus(ev: any) {
    console.log(ev);
}
```

how to fix the

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '[object Object]'

When selecting on the passed or failed, there's an error which is Cannot assign to read only property 'id' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: Why you are using `formControlName` and `ngModel` both? it makes no sense.

Comment: @Plochie it should be only one?

Comment: I'll update the code

Comment: @Plochie is it correct now? i'm trying to achieve here is to if its true it will display in console true if false it will display false in console

Comment: can you post complete form from html?

Comment: @Plochie done update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `(change)` to `(ngModelChange)` event.

```html
<nz-radio-group formControlName="status" name="status" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
```

Documentation:
https://ng.ant.design/components/radio/en#nz-radio-group