# How to fix the radio group in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```
<nz-radio-group formControlName="status" name="status" (change)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                      <label nz-radio nzValue="true">Passed</label>
                      <label nz-radio nzValue="false">Failed</label>
                    </nz-radio-group>
```

***list.component.ts***

```
onChangeStatus(event: any) {
console.log(event);
}
```

What I want here is to detect if the value of radio is true or false. but when I try to check in the dev console it doesn't display if its true or false.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can subscribe to value changes on the `status: FormControl` variable in your TS file. `this.status.valueChanges.subscribe((isChecked: boolean) => {});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bind in reactive forms which is the formcontrolname and ngmodel in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340908/how-to-bind-in-reactive-forms-which-is-the-formcontrolname-and-ngmodel-in-angula)

Comment: @Plochie yes sir.

Answer (score 3):

I think You have to change your event name, change event will not work here.

replace change event to ngModelChange

(ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)"

I tried using below example

```
<nz-radio-group 
    [formControl]="favoriteSeason" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
      <label nz-radio nzValue="A">A</label>
      <label nz-radio nzValue="B">B</label>
      <label nz-radio nzValue="C">C</label>
      <label nz-radio nzValue="D">D</label>
    </nz-radio-group>
```

into ts flie

```
favoriteSeason = new FormControl('A');
  onChangeStatus(ev){

    console.log(ev);
  }
```

Hope this will work

thanks